# A very basic Android app is incompatible on a lot of devices

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-manifest, compatibility, incompatibility

So I have an app with some very basic functionalities, including writing to external Download folder, saving files to the external cache, and having an Intent that opens an email app. Yet my app is only compatible on 372 devices. I was wondering what I'm doing that's causing my app to be incompatible?

My AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp">
    <supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ResultsActivity"></activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mycompany.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.0.1"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        jackOptions {
            enabled true
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `minSdkVersion` is 24. According to [google](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Platform) only ~7% of the devices support API level 24 or greater. Consider decreasing it and testing your app on those API levels

Comment: Thanks. Lowered minSdkVersion to 19 and now compatible with over 7,000 devices.